# Call a method in index.cshtml PageModel in javascript in Asp.NetCore

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

I need to call a delete method in my index.cshtml.cs from JavaScript. The reason for that is I want to use a modal or a sweet alert confirmation before deleting. Using my present code, I can get the "Id" of the record I want to delete but I am stuck on how to call my delete method in index.cshtml.cs and pass the Id to it. I don't like to use the API controller.

Here is my code.

**index.cshtml**

```
<td>
                                <button
                                        data-id="@item.Id"
                                        data-body-message="Are you sure?"
                                        class="btn btn-danger btn-sm delete">
                                    Delete
                                </button>
                                <a asp-page="Upsert" asp-route-id="@item.Id" class="btn btn-success btn-sm text-white">Edit</a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
```

**index.cshtml.cs**

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostDeleteAsync(int id)
        {
            var customer = await context.Customers.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == id);
            if (customer == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            context.Customers.Remove(customer);
            await context.SaveChangesAsync();

            return RedirectToPage("Index");
        }
```

**customer.js**

```
$((function () {
    var url;
    var redirectUrl;
    var target;
    var id;

    $('body').append(`
                    <div class="modal fade" id="deleteModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
                    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                        <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Warning</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body delete-modal-body">
                            
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" id="cancel-delete">Cancel</button>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" id="confirm-delete">Delete</button>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    </div>`);

    //Delete Action
    $(".delete").on('click', (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        target = e.target;
        var Id = $(target).data('id');
        id = Id;
        var bodyMessage = $(target).data('body-message');

        $(".delete-modal-body").text(bodyMessage);
        $("#deleteModal").modal('show');
    });

    $("#confirm-delete").on('click', () => {
        debugger;
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '?handler=Delete()',
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data);
            },
            error: function (error) {
                alert("Error: " + error);
            }
        })
    });

}()));
```

I am very new to ASP.net Core MVC.

Comment: Inside ajax on `"#confirm-delete"` assign url as: `url: 'controllerName/OnPostDeleteAsync/ + id'`

Comment: @Imran It is in my index.cshtml. It is not in a controller Sir.